# How to connect Xdmx and android Xserver?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, android

I run:

```
$ Xdmx :1 -display 192.168.1.137:0
```

The output:

```
(II) dmx: Generation:         1
(II) dmx: DMX version:        1.2.20070424 (DMX Project)
(II) dmx: DMX Build OS:       Linux 2.6.42-34-generic i686 (Ubuntu)
(II) dmx: DMX Build Compiler: gcc 4.6.3
(II) dmx: DMX Execution OS:   Linux 3.2.0-37-lowlatency #37-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 28 13:38:48 UTC 2013
(II) dmx: DMX Execution Host: alex-Inspiron
(II) dmx: MAXSCREENS:         16
(II) dmx: Using configuration from command line
(II) dmx: Added 192.168.1.137:0 at 0 0
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: Name of display: 192.168.1.137:0
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: Version number:  11.0
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: Vendor string:   Open source
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: Vendor release:  0
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: Dimensions:      1024x720 pixels
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: 1 depths on screen 0:  32
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: Depth of root window:  32 planes (32)
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: Number of colormaps:   1 min, 1 max
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: Options: backing-store yes, save-unders no
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: Window Manager running: no
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: 1024x720+0+0 on 1024x720 at depth=32, bpp=32
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: 0x01 TrueColor   32b 8b/rgb 256 0xff0000 0xff00 0x00ff *
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: DPMS not supported
(**) dmx: dmxBECreateColormap: No visual found
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: (request) s=1024x720+0+0 r=1024x720+0+0 @0,0 (0) (be=1024x720 depth=32 bpp=32)
(II) dmx[o0/192.168.1.137:0]: s=1024x720+0+0 r=1024x720+0+0 @0,0 (be=1024x720 depth=32 bpp=32)
(II) dmx: Using 1024x720 as global bounding box
(II) dmx: XSync batching with 100 ms interval
(II) dmx: Shadow framebuffer support disabled

Fatal server error:
no screens found
```

How to locate the problem?

Comment: Author of Xserver answer in blog: "No, the DMX extension isn’t implemented. The only extensions currently supported are Shape, XGE, and BigRequests."